# Resources for clean pure Typescript app architecture

Tags: typescript, api, architecture

I need to create a pure Typescript application which connects to database using an API. I am looking for an example of cleanest possible architecture. I'd like my app to:

- fetch data from an API and map this data into Typescript objects
- store it somehow (without any persistence, just for the session)
- react to user iterface and call proper data access layer functions
- pass everything to external library which will graph the data

Here is the sketch of how I imagine this should look like[image]

Main issue is that until now I've been creating this stuff mostly in React and now I am forced to use plain Typescript. I've fallen into bad architecture trap too many times and would like this one to be the cleanest it could be.

Any good resources? Probably simple clean app code example (without graphing library, just with simple data presentation) would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi! Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Questions asking for recommendations for off-site resources are *specifically* off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use this approach: https://morphological.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/5-layer-architecture/

It's not Typescript specific, but should suit it fine.  I'm makin the assumption that by "Pure" & "Clean" you mean separation of concerns - including use of Dependency Injection to ensure you have flexibility for the future.

The use of layers below refers to logical separation within your codebase.

To apply that to your situation:

[image]

- UI and application logic in separate layers.
- Dumb DTOs / POCO's in a common layer which provides the common vocabulary across the system.  This would **not** include data-mapping related objects that were specific to any of the database or API providers - those would live inside the data/API provider in question.
- The logic layer interfaces with databases, APIs, external components, etc, via code interfaces, represented by the abstraction layer.
- Each "provider" (database, API, whatever) is defined within the abstraction layer by one or more interfaces each (being mindful of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)).
- Each provider can then have one or more concrete implementations, which are loaded at runtime using a dependency injection mechanism of some kind.

The graph component is abstracted out just like the other providers.  The reason for the is that:

- They (providers) all provide "stuff" (data / functionality) which the logic layer wants to consume/interact with - but we want to keep these loosely-coupled.
- They are all (or are likely to be) specialized - having various dependencies which we want to keep as far away from the rest of the code-base as possible.

If you expose (not consume) an externally facing API, then there's a case for putting that in the representation layer (up there logically next to UI), but it doesn't look like you have need for that.

The dependency injection / inversion can be as simple or as complex as you want it to be.